# Convenient shortcut for integrals

Tags: macros

I just create a shortcut especially for definite integrals. But, the message log said that I had a mistake (an error). Could someone tell me why and help me design a better `\newcommand` code for me, especially on definite integrals?

Here is the code that I've tried :

```
\newcommand{\intl}[3][]{\displaystyle{\int_{#1}^{#2} {#3}\,\,dd x}}
```

Oh ya, this `\dd` stands for `\mathrm{d}`. And `{#3}` means the function that I would like to integrate it.

**Edit starts here** (Thanks to @Andrew for the advice)            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is my sample :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}} % <--- Editted here
\newcommand{\intl}[3][]{\displaystyle{\int_{#1}^{#2} {#3}\,\,dd x}}

\begin{document}
$$\intl{1}{5}{x}$$
\\
This is hoped to be like this,
$$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{5}x\dd x$$ % <--- Editted here
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you expand your code snippet to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code. This said, I wonder if you just want `\newcommand{\intl}[3]{\displaystyle{\int_{#1}^{#2} {#3}\,\,dd x}}` (so, no `[]`). Without seeing how you are using this and your error it is not possible to say.

Comment: Hi @Andrew ! Thanks for giving some advice to me, hope my additional info could help you.

Comment: Unrelated: `\text{d}` is the wrong command to use in this context, use `\mathrm{d}` instead. The `\text` command does not do what you (and many othes think it does). Additionally: your example does not compile as you haven't added the definition of `\dd` and you spelled `\displaystyle` wrong in the last equation.

Comment: @daleif done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it a shortcut? `\int_1^5 x\dd x` and `\intl{1}{5}{x}` differ by just a few keystrokes (define `\dd` by `\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`). But the former is clearer and more flexible: do your integrals only have the variable *x*?

Comment: What about the other hard functions? I just use "x" as the model, though.

Comment: @WiloryLu You don't need `\displaystyle`. If the integral is in a displayed formula, the style is automatically selected; in an inline formula it will destroy the line spacing leaving big white bands around the line: nothing I'd like to see printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. ($$..$$ should not be used in a LaTeX document. \displaystyle is default within \[..\] environment)

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}} 
 \newcommand{\intl}[3]{\displaystyle\int^{#2}_{#1}{#3}\,\dd x}
 
 \begin{document}
 \[\intl{1}{5}{x}\]
 \\
 This is hoped to be like this,
 \[\int_{1}^{5}x\dd x\] 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Note that if your editor is capable of producing macros it is better to use this functionality. This makes the code easier to read because it is made up of well-defined and documented LaTeX-only macros. For instance, yasnippet within Emacs is able to produce such macros.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! But why did you substitute #1 (mine) to #2 (yours)? And again thanks for the explaination, I just figured that out now.

Comment: no teason, just my habits.